# How to capture all the output from a github action "uses"?

Tags: github-actions

All the examples demonstrate setting output from a run:, but is there a way to capture everything that will go to the logs if I have a workflow step that does the following, so I can take another step based on the results?

```
      - uses: gr2m/merge-schedule-action@275900b9009be628ed52cbbe75a1f4f56431322d
        with:
          # Merge method to use. Possible values are merge, squash or
          # rebase. Default is merge.
          merge_method: merge
          #  Time zone to use. Default is UTC.
          time_zone: "America/New_York"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: What results are you expecting from the provided step?

Comment: The step will sometimes log a string indicating that it merged a release (something like "merge completed").   If it does, and only if it does, I would like to take further actions.

Comment: What happens when it is not time to merge? Action fails or exits with success?

Comment: Exits with success and a message is logged saying nothing was found to merge.
Cutting to the chase: I don't want to edit the code of this action I rely on, and the statuses are the same in either case, so I'd like to take an action based on the output it's logging.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any Gtihub Action that would easily download the job logs. You could with some Python scraping script download logs manually. The instruction to download logs can be found here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/using-workflow-run-logs#downloading-logs.